# C# Random.Next - never returns the upper bound?

Tags: c#, random

```
random.Next(0,5)
```

It never returns the 5 (but sometimes returns the 0.) Why? I thought these are just boundary values that can be returned. Thanks

Comment: Why was it done this way? It's needlessly confusing.

Comment: Why? Probably because of this:

var randomValue = myArray[rand.Next(0, myArray.Length)];

Comment: I found this documentation faster than retyping code and triggering intellisense or searching the MSDN library. You don't usually type code when debugging or _reading_ code. I intuitively read "maxValue" as "maximum possible value", not "maximum value minus one". No need to have told the OP to RTFM.

Comment: I know I'm late here but I'm actually completely flabbergasted by this. Like everyone else in the world,  I read "maxValue" as the largest number this function will return. I'm pretty sure I have broken code in production because of this.

Comment: oddly, it will return the maxValue if minValue==maxValue. Likewise Next(0) (ostensibly an implicit minValue of 0 will return 0 only. Pretty wonky in an inconsequential way.

Comment: @JoshSutterfield actually according to the manual "If minValue equals maxValue, **minValue** is returned."

Comment: The OP is asking "WHY?" and no one has seem to answer this. I'm interested in why they designed it this way.

Comment: @Xonatron That's a question (already asked an answered before, which one of the comments below points out) that is better suited for the SoftwareEngineering SE, not StackOverflow. That would be the preferred place to speculate on development methodologies.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The `maxValue` for the upper-bound in the `Next()` method is **exclusive**—the range includes `minValue`, `maxValue-1`, and all numbers in between.

Comment: Any thoughts on why they chose to make one inclusive, and the other exclusive? Seems kinda peculiar...

Comment: One reason of which I can think is `array[random.Next(0, array.Length)]`

Comment: Yea, makes sense for generating collection indices, I can imagine that being an important use case.

Comment: The Name maxValue (as the Parameter is called) is actively misleading. It should be called upper Bound. As the Maximum is always an element of a set.

Comment: @AntonioNakicAlfirevic - see here for the reasoning behind this behaviour: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/311250/exclusive-upper-bound-in-random-number-range/311253

Comment: To add to the confusion, maxValue is no longer exclusive if you pass identical values for minValue and maxValue. The description "Returns a random integer that is within a specific range" is also misleading.

Comment: Could you add the answer to the true question which is WHY?

Comment: @Harry Berry - Agree 100%, it's an extremely poor name for the parameter.  They should have just named it exclusiveUpperBound.

Answer (score 14):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) says the upper bound is exclusive. Exclusive means that it is not included in the possible return set. In a more mathematical notation `0 <= x < 5` in this case.

Comment: This is not true for min=max. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.

Comment: @jasdefer In that case, why does it return `minValue` instead of `maxValue`?

Comment: @qxz I am just talking about the case: `minValue` = `maxValue`. Here it does not matter if `minValue` or `maxValue` is returned because they are equal.  `minValue <= x <  maxValue` is not true. If `minValue` = `maxValue` = 0, x = 0 is returned and 0<0 is not true.

Answer (score 7):

Straight from the documentation:

```
 Summary:
   Returns a random number within a specified range.

 Parameters:
   minValue:
     The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.

   maxValue:
     The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be
     greater than or equal to minValue.

 Returns:
     A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue;
     that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If
     minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.
```

If you look at the parameters, you will see that `minValue` is inclusive (which is why your 0 occurs) and `maxValue` is exclusive (your 5 never occurs).

Answer (score 2):

Good way to remember it is to consider max as amount of numbers from which it takes random number.
So `random.Next(0,2)` means that it takes random out of 2 numbers starting from 0: 0 and 1.

Comment: This is a good way of remembering it only if the lower bound given is 0. It is not true that e.g. random.Next(1,2) takes a random choice of 2 numbers starting from 1.

Answer (score 1):

This has been written a long time ago but I will comment anyway. I think the main reason for that design decision is that most if not all random number generator at their core generate numbers from 0 to 2^32-1. So if you specify Int32.MaxValue you will never get that number. Having an exception for one number must have been not acceptable to the designers so they decided to have the bracket exclusive. Problem solved!

Answer (score -2):

When you just look in Google for "c# random" and follow the first links to the method of desire you get here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329893(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329893%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

And there is no hint about the exclusiveness of the upper bound. They must have found the mistake in the code and corrected it with documentation.

So it is important to always check the version of the framework when looking at the documentation. Even when working with old versions of the framework, it is worth to have a look at the newer documentation.

Comment: Followed the link you posted and found this:  "Return Value - 
A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not MaxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned."

Comment: As dbasnett says, the documentation *does* specify the behaviour here. Not only that, but this is the *conventional* way of defining a range for something like random numbers. Your guess that this was actually a bug is a poor one, IMO.

Comment: Kind of non-intuitive to allow the maxValue to be the same as the minValue, since that should cause the set of valid values to be empty always