# cycle never reaching final value

Tags: c#, random

This is my random unique numbers generator I try to create for my cards software. It generates numbers and write into array OK. I have problem with the loop here. when integer i reaches 29, it stops growing and code cycles infinitely and never reaches 30, which would stop the loop.

Without the if statement it works, but it won't fill the range needed.

---

fixed the code, now works OK, the initial value in array was the problem. now I ged needed 0-29 values

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[] rndCards = new int[30];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.Text = @"random numbers";


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        rndCards = new int[30];
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (i < 30)
        {
        int cardTest = rnd.Next(0, 30);
            while (rndCards.Contains(cardTest))
            {
                cardTest++;
                if (cardTest == 31)
                {
                cardTest = 1;
                }
            }
            rndCards[i] = cardTest;
            i++;    

        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < 30)
        {
            rndCards[i] = rndCards[i] -1;
            richTextBox1.Text += rndCards[i] + ", ";
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you considered a shuffling algorithm instead?

Comment: uhm, no, because if I solve the int i problem, then this is solved and usable.

Comment: You while(rnd.Cards.Contains(cardTest) block causes the infinite loop when i=29.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem lies in the simple fact that the array already contains the number 0 when you create it (because each item of an array is initialized to the default value for its member's type) That's why you should start your i from 1 and not zero.

```
int i = 1;
```

### Alternative Simpler Approach:

You can do this as a simple random number generation:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rndCards = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

foreach(var card in rndCards)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: no, random generating is correct. int i is problematic. I DO NEED random numbers 0 - 29

Comment: @MorellSunweaver Then your array needs to be of size 29 and not 30. Also change the condition in your while statement.

Comment: @MorellSunweaver also check the alternative way i have just posted. I think it is simpler.

Comment: Size of array is correct. while numbering IN array begins from 0, 30 is number of rows begins from 1, so that is not wrong.

Comment: @MorellSunweaver the array already contains the number 0 when you first initialize it because 0 is the default for int type. So just start i from 1 and everything is going to work fine. I edited my answer.

Comment: "array already contains the number 0" You were right, this is the problem. Thanks. so the solution is to get numbers 1 - 30 and then to all of them give -1. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

`rnd.Next(0,30)` would return a random number from 0-29.

From the documentation for [`Random.Next(Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Next(Int32, Int32) overload returns random integers that range from minValue to maxValue – 1. However, if maxValue equals minValue, the method returns minValue.

Use `int cardText = rnd.Next(0, 31);`, and this should solve your issue.

Comment: no, random generating is correct. int i is problematic

Comment: The while loop is going from 0-29, incrementing each time. I don't see why that wouldn't work. (It will do 30 loops).

Comment: right, that's it, it should, but when reaching 29, it wont get into value 30 to stop cycling, so it cycles with i  29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29,...

Comment: @MorellSunweaver I feel like just using a simple reordering thing would work a lot better: `Enumerable.Range(0, 30).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound is exclusive ([C# Random.Next - never returns the upper bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063269/c-sharp-random-next-never-returns-the-upper-bound)).

```
int cardTest = rnd.Next(0, 31);
```

Comment: no, random generating is correct. int i is problematic