# Random.Range not changing its outcome each time its called, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, delegates

I am using random range to choose a between enemy types to spawn.

```
IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        int randAmount = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minAmount, maxAmount); // Determine quantity of enemies to be spawned
        int randType = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1); // Determine which enemy is spawned
        enemies[randType](randAmount); // Call enemy type, then amount
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
        StartCoroutine(Spawn()); // Loop
    }
```

When attaching to unity with the debugger, I can see that `randAmount`changes each time the coroutine is called, however the `randType` has not changed from 0,  I have been testing over and over and I am starting to think it is no longer bad luck.

I know that the first variable is working correctly, is there anyway to ensure that the second one works correctly, or an alternative method to get a random number between 0 and 1 each time the coroutine is called.

Comment: `static function Range (min : int, max : int) : int`
Description
Returns a random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive] (Read Only).

Comment: @OmBiEaTer, I don't think they count the upper bound number so you have to go +1

Comment: `Random.Range(0, 2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Random.Next - never returns the upper bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063269/c-sharp-random-next-never-returns-the-upper-bound) < this one is .Net's random but exactly the same issue

Comment: Not a dupe - it's the Unity API, not the MS C# API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Unity Manual :

```
public static float Range(float min, float max);
```

> Description
>   Returns a random float number between and min [inclusive] and max [inclusive] (Read Only).
>   Note that max is **inclusive**, so using Random.Range( 0.0f, 1.0f ) could return 1.0 as a value.

But

```
public static int Range(int min, int max);
```

> Description
>   Returns a random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive] (Read Only).
>   Note that max is **exclusive**, so using Random.Range( 0, 10 ) will return values between 0 and 9. If max equals min, min will be returned.

So the solution is change from (0,1) to (0,2).

Answer (score 5):

Unity's [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) second parameter is exclusive which means that Unity does not include it. It includes max-1.

If you want to generate random number between `0` and `1`, you have to pass `2` to the second parameter. That should be `Random.Range(0, 2)`.

Comment: @EpicKip I don't answer duplicates. I close all duplicates. **This is not a duplicate**. The link you provided is not a duplicate to this. 1. OP is using `Random.Range` not `Random.Next`.  2.Generating random number in Unity is different from generating random number in with C# standard API. Notice the API I linked in this answer.

Comment: I'm not actually sure why I didn't begin googling this question before asking, sorry for that one.