# C# - Generating random username with up to 3 digits puts 4 digits sometimes

Tags: c#, random

I have to write method to generate random username which contains 8 characters, consisting of lowercase letters and up to 3 digits. So I wrote following method:

```
    public string UsernameGenerator()
    {
        const string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        const string digits = "0123456789";
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        int numberOfNumerics = random.Next(0, 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {        
            var l = letters[random.Next(0, letters.Length)];
            builder.Append(l);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumerics; i++)
        {
            int replaceIndex = random.Next(0, 8);
            var d = digits[random.Next(0, digits.Length)];
            builder.Replace(builder[replaceIndex],d);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

However from time to time it generates username that contains 4 digits. My numberOfNumerics variable is `random.Next(0,4)`, according to documentation it should return random number from 0 to 3. It looks like additional number is duplicate of one of already used digits and it's often placed next to each other. Some examples of wrongly generated password:

> ko90w09q, qs2b22m6, yh38wa88, x66uvf36

And yes, changing `random.Next(0, 4);` to `random.Next(0, 3);` kinda solves the problem, because then it generates username with 3 digits from time to time, but it's indirectly solution for me. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @Trevor, the [upperbound of next is exclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063269/c-sharp-random-next-never-returns-the-upper-bound?utm_medium=organic)

Comment: @dlatikay Yes, sorry, I checked the documentation, and hence removed the comment.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) "maxValue: The **exclusive** upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue." So random.Next(0, 3) generates [0, 1, 2]

Comment: @Kamil: Is 0 numbers an option you want or should there always be at least 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is *not* caused by `Random.Next` since you loop only 3 numbers even if `Next` can return 4 because of your loop condition `i < numberOfNumerics`. So this is correct.

The error is caused by a wrong logic. You use:

```
builder.Replace(builder[replaceIndex],d);
```

That replaces all occurrences of a letter with your digit. You want to use:

```
builder[replaceIndex] = d;
```

But you should store the already replaced indexes otherwise you could replace the same:

```
var replacedIndexes = new HashSet<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumerics; i++)
{
    int replaceIndex = random.Next(0, builder.Length);
    while (!replacedIndexes.Add(replaceIndex))
        replaceIndex = random.Next(0, builder.Length);
    char d = digits[random.Next(0, digits.Length)];
    builder[replaceIndex] = d;
}
```

Comment: This is totally correct and your answer made it clear for me. Thank you and everyone very much for your help!

Comment: for clarity and readability, `numberOfNumerics` is a count and not an index and should really range from 1 to and including 3 (the way of how `Next` works in connection with the < in the loop mislead all of us "yeah-I-can-debug-it-in-my-head" contributors except Tim)

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, my previous answer was irrelevant to your issue. I'm writing a new better one now.

So, you generate some sequence of eight NON-UNIQUE characters. Say, it is "koabwbaq". Then you use

```
builder.Replace(builder[replaceIndex],d);
```

to replace ALL occurrances of 'a' with 9. You get "ko9bwb9q". Then you replace ALL 'b's with 0 and end up with "ko90w09q". That's it.

Comment: I just checked it and that is correct answer. But could you explain me why it replace all occurances of specific letter? I thought that if I provide index, it should only replace character with that index. Is there a method that would replace only specific character or should I go other way and make my only-letters string to use unique letters?

Comment: I just checked anser of @TimSchmelter and everything is clear for me now. Thank you adn everyone very much for help!