# generating a random number between 0 and 1 always returns 0

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to return a random number between 0 and 1, but it always returns 0.

Code:

```
int rnd = new Random().Next(0, 1);
```

Comment: You are assigning it to an int ... use a float or double variable

Comment: You should instantiate Random only once and get next from it and not create it every time again

Comment: As [this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5063276/5062791), "The maxValue for the upper-bound in the Next() method is exclusive—the range includes minValue, maxValue-1, and all numbers in between.".

Use `int rnd = new Random().Next(0, 2);`

Comment: *between* 0 and 1, or *either* 0 *or* 1? Your code is inconsistent with your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Random.Next` takes an *inclusive* min, and an *exclusive* max - so the only possible result for `Random.Next(0, 1)` is 0.

If you're trying to generate a zero or a 1, such as a coin flip, use:

```
int result = new Random().Next(0, 2);
```

To generate a number between 0 and 1, change it to:

```
double result = new Random().NextDouble(0, 1);
```

It's hard to tell from your example, as you're saying "between", but assigning the result to an `int`, and calling a function that returns an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

There are no integers between `0` and `1`. Since the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive, you'll always get a `0`. You should use [`NextDouble`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble) instead:

```
double rnd = new Random().NextDouble();
```